# PHP exercise with cookies

Tags: php

i need to get score +10 when i answer the question right but it is not working here is my code:

Hi thanks for the answers, i am now trying this but the score isnt going up by 10 if i answer the question good:

```
    <?php
    // de functie rand() bepaalt een random getal tussen het eerste en       tweede opgegeven getal
$getal1 = rand (1, 10);
$getal2 = rand (1, 20);
$score = 0;

if(isset($_POST['verzend'])){
    $antwoord = $_POST['uitkomst'];
    $somantwoord = $getal1 * $getal2;

    if($antwoord == $somantwoord)
    {
        $score + 10;
    }
}

echo $score;
```

HTML

```
<form method='post' action='index.php'>
 <input name='getal1' type='text' disabled value='$getal1'>&nbsp;*&nbsp;
 <input name='getal2' type='text' disabled value='$getal2'> =
 <input name='uitkomst' type='text' value='' id='uitkomst'>
 <input type='submit' value='verzend' name='verzend'>
 </form>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: is something in particular not working? or have you started solving the problem and have encountered a specific task you do not know how to accomplish? if so, what? try breaking down the problem for yourself and solving it in chunks. then, when you encounter a problem, you'll have a more specific thing to search for, and you might even be able to google the answer

Comment: Why do you need cookies (other than the session cookie)?  Why do you provide code that has obvious (fatal) syntax errors.  If the exercise is too hard for you, you should go to simpler exercises, or follow good tutorials.

Comment: I won't make your homework for you, maar een paar tips: No need to store the result (uitkomst) inside a cookie, you probably want to store the score in that cookie. (For exercise purposes that is, in real life you'd need to use the session for that, or it would be very easy to beat the game). You'll need `$_GET` to read the total the user provided, as well as the actual numbers, the calculation and check should be trivial. And why the `echo heredoc`, why not just close your php block and continue in html?

Comment: @JonStirling did edit

Comment: @Pevara I did edit the question

Comment: You generate 2 new numbers, and compare those to the total provided by the user. You obviously need to use the numbers from the previous request, as those are the ones the user based his answer on. And only generate new number if needed. (mag ik je ook aanraden om code ALTIJD in het engels te schrijven. Al was het alleen maar om ze makkelijker op SO te kunnen posten. En probeer zinvollere namen te verzinnen, bv. `$calculatedResult` en $providedResult`, en een vermenigvuldiging is geen som ;) )

Comment: `$score += 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
// de functie rand() bepaalt een random getal tussen het eerste en       tweede opgegeven getal
$getal1 = rand(1, 10);
$getal2 = rand(1, 20);
$score = 0;

if(isset($_POST['verzend'])) {
    $antwoord = (int)$_POST['uitkomst'];
    $somantwoord = $getal1 * $getal2;

    if($antwoord === $somantwoord) {
        $score += 10;
    }
}

echo $score;
```